# WCF singleton service with multiple endpoints?

Tags: wcf, serialization, singleton, wcf-endpoint

I have a singleton wcf service (`InstanceContextMode.Single`) i.e MyService with multiple endpoints namely netmsmq and http. The call to netmsmq works fine but when I call it as :

```
Binding bin = new BasicHttpBinding();
            EndpointAddress end = new EndpointAddress("http://localhost/WcfService1/MyService.svc");
            var obje = new ChannelFactory<IMyService>(bin, end);
            obje.Open();
            var factory = obje.CreateChannel();

            factory.MethodCall(this) ;  //this is ref of MyService1 obj
            obje.Close();
```

in the ctor of Myservice1 I get a not Serializable exception at the line:

```
factory.MethodCall(this);
```

After this I added the `[Serializable]` and `[KnownType(typeof(MyService1))]` attributes on MyService1 but now I get a timeout exception If I call MethodCall method.

**EDIT:**
MethodCall method signature is as follows in MyService:

```
public void MethodCall(IMyService1 obj){}
```

where MyService1 implements IService.

**EDIT 2:**
Turns out that the http call is trying to hit the address of the netmsmq. I am doing:

```
 Binding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
                Uri via = new Uri("http://localhost/WcfService1/MyService.svc");
                 my_host.AddServiceEndpoint(type, binding, "",via);
```

whereas for netmsmq I am doing:

```
var contractName = serviceContract + serviceType.Name; 

nbinding.CustomDeadLetterQueue = new Uri(customDlq);
my_host.AddServiceEndpoint(contractName, nbinding, "net.msmq://localhost/private/MyService.svc");
```

I am using service activation in web.config and I have set `multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"` in service hosting environment. The error that I get is that :

> > "The HTTP request to 'http://localhost/WcfService1/MyService.svc' has exceeded the allotted timeout of 00:00:59.9940000. The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout."

**EDIT 3:**
The wsdl location for http are shown as:

`http://localhost/WcfService1/MyService.svc`

and for msmq as:

```
net.msmq://localhost/private/WcfService1/MyService.svc
```

The contracts are all `[OperationContract (IsOneWay = true)]`

Both services are hosted on IIS and are part of a single project. I was thinking that maybe I cannot use multiple endpoints of a singleton service. Is this the reason? I have been at it for 2 days thought fresh pair of eyes might do the trick.
Any help would be appreciated. I can post the stack trace if required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, a wcf singleton service can have multiple endpoints.

The problem was solved by using `[ServiceKnownType(typeof(MyService1))]` over the method declaration in IMyService interface. Like,

```
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(MyService1))]
public void MethodCall(IMyService1 obj);
```

It was a serialization issue.